# openapi generator is not generating code for allOf

Tags: swagger, openapi, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-cli

I'm using `@openapitools/openapi-generator-cli` in my project for generation of API as following:

`npx @openapitools/openapi-generator-cli generate`

which works fine.

Lately I had to generate the API from a swagger file named `UserAdressesDto.yml` that has `allOf` property:

```
allOf:
  - $ref: '../../common/UserDto.yml'
type: object
properties:
  adresses:
    type: array
    items:
      $ref: '../../common/AddressDto.yml'
```

But the generator fails to generate the right code, and the generated file looks like this:

```
import { AddressDto } from './address-dto';
import { UserDto} from './user-dto';

/**
 * @type UserAdressesDto
 * @export
 */
export type UserAdressesDto = UserDto;
```

By the way, this works fine in the `Swagger Editor`.

Normally this generated file should look like this:

```
export interface UserAdressesDto {
  /**
   * The user ID.
   * @type {number}
   * @memberof UserAdressesDto
   */
  id?: number;
  /**
   * The user name
   * @type {string}
   * @memberof UserAdressesDto
   */
  name?: string;
  /**
   *
   * @type {Array<AddressDto>}
   * @memberof UserAdressesDto
   */
  adresses?: Array<AddressDto>;
}
```

I checked the openapi documentation and there was an option to add: https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/customization/#openapi-normalizer

So I tried this:

`npx @openapitools/openapi-generator-cli generate --openapi-normalizer REF_AS_PARENT_IN_ALLOF=true`

But then I got this error message:

```
[error] Found unexpected parameters: [--openapi-normalizer, REF_AS_PARENT_IN_ALLOF=true]
```

How can I solve this?

**Edit:**

This is my openapitools.json

```
{
  "$schema": "node_modules/@openapitools/openapi-generator-cli/config.schema.json",
  "spaces": 2,
  "generator-cli": {
    "version": "6.4.0",
    "generators": {
      "v3.1": {
        "generatorName": "typescript-axios",
        "output": "#{cwd}/src/generated/openapi",
        "glob": "./openapi/source/api.yml",
        "additionalProperties": {
          "ngVersion": "6.1.7",
          "npmName": "restClient",
          "supportsES6": "true",
          "npmVersion": "6.9.0",
          "withInterfaces": true,
          "withSeparateModelsAndApi": true,
          "modelPackage": "model",
          "apiPackage": "api"
        },
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Edit 2:**

Changing the swagger file to:

```
allOf:
  - $ref: '../../common/UserDto.yml'
  - type: object
    properties:
      adresses:
        type: array
        items:
          $ref: '../../common/AddressDto.yml'
```

This did work, but the generated file looked like this:

```
import { AddressDto } from './address-dto';
import { UserDto } from './user-dto';
import { UserAdressesDtoAllOf} from './user-addresses-dto-all-of';

export type UserAdressesDto = UserDto & UserAdressesDtoAllOf;
```

and `user-addresses-dto-all-of.ts`:

```
export interface UserAdressesDtoAllOf{

  adresses?: Array<AddressDto>;
}
```

This has two issues: it created a new interface `UserAdressesDtoAllOf` which doesn't make any sense when the generated file can just look like this:

```
interface UserAdressesDto {
  id?: number;
  name?: string;
  adresses?: Array<AddressDto>;
}
```

the second issue is that it imports `AddressDto` when it didn't need it inside the file.

Comment: The cli command you've provided is invalid.  I'm assuming you cut out parts that you felt weren't needed for this question, however, sharing your full cli command will help in determining why you received the `unexpected parameters` error (I assume your cli structure is incorrect).  It would also help to know which [generator](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators) you are using and, if available to your generator, which library you are using as well.  Please share your cli command.  Also, are you using the latest version (`6.5.0`)?  If not, which version are you using?

Comment: @tbatch please check my update, btw I tried to set the version of the generator to `6.5.0` but it didn't work, that latst version of the genertor from `openapi-generator-cli` is `6.4.0`

Comment: My apologies.  the current version is indeed `6.4.0`.  That was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest stable version (v7.3.0) of openapi-generator, please set `REFACTOR_ALLOF_WITH_PROPERTIES_ONLY=true` in openapi normalizer: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/customization.md#openapi-normalizer to handle schemas with allOf and properties defined in the same level.

In the next major version (v8.0.0), we may enable this rule by default.

Comment: I just checked.

Comment: For me when I use withSeparateModulesAndApis it neither generator a seperate model for all nor merging it with the base model